# EV3 Color Sensor protocol

Tags: uart, lego-mindstorms

I am facing problem related protocol EV3 Color sensor. ( Background: I have implemented the embedded system with Uart on FPGA,receiving information from EV3 color Sensor and write the C program to operate Sensor Color mode. It sent all correct initial information but when I sent back acknowledge and changed baud to 57600, Sensor not sent correct data ( I am only getting zeros with some irrelevant HEX codes.) I want to ask that Should I sent the nack first then expected data. OR something you know about this step.

Initial information OF EV3 Color sensor:

> 00FF (401DA2490502B1 TYPE,ID,MODE) (5200E100004C SPEED 57600)
>
> (MODES and its information:
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
>   04 ACKNOWLEDEG

protocol that I following is from this website.https://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/wiki/UART%20Sensor%20Protocol/

Comment: It seem to be power problem, sensor could not receive the ack from fpga board, Since pmod provide only 3,3 V

Comment: Solved: By using the voltage shifter